# Get certain intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So lets say i have 4 buttons , and each button contains an intent which navigates to an activity.They all navigate to a single same activity . When i click the first button i want that new activity to show "Hi" , When i click the second button i want it to show "Bye" and so on . How do i do that ?
Here is a simple code to start with

```
public class Intentt extends Activity {
Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intentt);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass some data through intent extras, or intent extra `Bundle`:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra(id, 453);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Example:

```
Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intentt);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.ID_ACTION, MainActivity.ACTION_1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.ID_ACTION, MainActivity.ACTION_2);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And then in that activity you can switch on that values getting them like that:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
int id = intent.getIntExtra("id",-1);
```

and then use the `if-elseif-else` or `switch` statement(s) to change the actions based on the passed action, so you can display your messages

To properly recieve them you need to set activity's launchMode to "**standard**" [because of **this bug**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17137) in `AndroidManifest.xml` and create

```
public static final int ACTION_1 = 1;
public static final int ACTION_2 = 2;
public static final int ACTION_NULL = -1;
public static final String ID_ACTION = "action_id";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(ID_ACTION, -1);

    if (id == ACTION_NULL) {
        Log.d("TAG", "id is null");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "id is null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == ACTION_1) {
        Log.i("TAG", "ALLOHA! from button 1");
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aloha from button 1!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (id == ACTION_2) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Hello from button 2");
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.thi,"Hello from button 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do the whole scenario please ? I didnt get it very well . Just do it with too buttons and i will do the rest .

Comment: take a look please : ) Do you want the first activity your "intentActivity" know what to display and transfer it to MainActivity or Main will know? like on my example?

Comment: Okay i did exactly as you said , but it's not printing out a toast ! It's just navigating. Though i repleced the log.d with a toast

Comment: Easy, just add the toast lines : )

Comment: I did ! It's not printing it out . Even i tried different actions , didnt work :(

'Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button 2!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'

Comment: Ok, im going to test it

Comment: Ok, i've got it up and running. single top is going to fire onCreate OR onNewIntent (you never know) so you need to fire that code in both places OR make activity `launchMode="standard"` and move the `onNewIntent` code to `onCreate`

Comment: How can i move the onNewIntent to onCreate :O Impossible

Comment: Just check the last piece of code in the answer ; ) Test it, its `00:40` at my clock

Comment: Alright ! It worked , thankks alot ;) Stay in touch , cuz i might have another question . This topic wasnt my main point though lol . THanks

Comment: So how can i apply this to a fragment class ? I,m doing in normally but it's returning me the " id is null "

Comment: Didnt get it :( , It's a different case i guess . Check my question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193677/fragment-returning-null-from-intent/31193921#31193921

Comment: I cant help you with Fragments, i have never had a time to learn deeply about them

Answer (score 1):

In each intent you could pass parameterts

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);
i.putExtra("KEY_MESSAGE", "Hola amigo");
```

In the other activity

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 String message = i.getStringExtra("KEY_MESSAGE")
 Toast.make(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Re write the button click listener as follows :

```
b1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Data","Hi");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
b2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Data","Hello");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
b3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Data","Bye");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
b4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("Data","See you");
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

In your MainActivity class onCreate Method, you can access the passed data by :

```
String passedData = getIntent().getStringExtra("Data");
```

you can use this passedData to display on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
    public class Intentt extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intentt);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button2:

                    Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra('"STRING_I_NEED"', "Hi");
                    startActivity(i)

                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    Intent i  = new Intent(Intentt.this,MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra('"STRING_I_NEED"', "Bye");
                    startActivity(i)

                    break;

                case R.id.button4:

                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
            }
    }
}
```

After that in your mainActivity retrieve string that you sent with:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String s = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```